# how to get an array field value from a PHP file using jquery/Ajax in Symfony2?

Tags: php, jquery, html, symfony, twig

I am developing a social network web site using Symfony2. In fact, I would like to know how I can get an array field value from a PHP file using jquery/Ajax in Symfony2. Among the files that I have in my project folder there are two files: test.html.twig and moslem1.php. The code of each of that two files is below:

The code of test.html.twig:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/src/jquery.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/moslem1.php')}}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(data1) {
                        var id=data1.id;
                        document.write(id);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code of moslem1.php:

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jqcalendar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $notification = array('id'=>$row['Id'],'subject'=>$row['Subject'],'location'=>$row['Location'],'description'=>$row['Description'],'starttime'=>$row['StartTime'],'endtime'=>$row['EndTime']);
}
echo json_encode($notification);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The issue is whenever I run the file test.html.twig it displays the out below:

undefined

What is strange is that it works when I put the code of the file test.html.twig in a html file. in fact I created two other files (not in Symfony2) which are t1.html and moslem1.php. their codes are as below:

The code of t1.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'moslem1.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(data1) {
                        var id=data1.id;
                        document.write(id);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code of moslem1.php:

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jqcalendar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $notification = array('id'=>$row['Id'],'subject'=>$row['Subject'],'location'=>$row['Location'],'description'=>$row['Description'],'starttime'=>$row['StartTime'],'endtime'=>$row['EndTime']);
}
echo json_encode($notification);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

As I said above, it works when I deal with a HTML file, but as I work on Symfony2 I have to use files with "html.twig" extension for view(output). So my question is what shall I do to make it works correctly with my twig file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to do that in a very very weird way. Instead of using `moslem1.php` create controllers' action which will return the JsonResponse. Try to refactor your code and when you're done, come back here again and ask if you're still facing some problems

Comment: @bartek: I think the problem is about the two lines:
var id=data1.id;
document.write(id);

For more explanation, please have a look at the comments that I typed for the answer of Mr. vobence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to put the php file into the bundles folder, it's a **huge security issue**. If you want an AJAX response then put it into the Controller.

Create a new action in the Controller as you normally do. Write the AJAX action and give back a `JSONResponse` as a response.

```
/**
* Return an ajax response
*/
public function ajaxAction(){
   // do the controller logic
   // $response is an array()
   return new JSONResponse($response);
}
```

Then in jQuery ajax set the url like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url/to/your/controller', // If you use the FOSJsRoutingBundle then it will be Routing.generate('route_name')
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data1) {
    var id=data1.id;
    document.write(id);
  }
});
```

In the new action you can use the `EntityManager` to access your database.

Here is a good article about this issue: http://symfony2forum.org/threads/5-Using-Symfony2-jQuery-and-Ajax

You should also consider to use the `FOSJsRoutingBundle` for javascript routing.
It's a very great bundle that allows you to generate routes in javascript files as you can do it in twig with the `path('path_name')` command.

Here is the GitHub project for this bundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

Try to understand the Symfony Request -> Response process, because if you don't follow it, it will cause serious problems for you.

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, by the way I changed the code of test.html.twig as below:

Comment: <html>
    <</head>
    <body>
        <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/src/jquery.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/moslem1.php')}}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(data1) {
                        
                        document.write(data1);
                    } }); });
        </script></body></html>

Comment: And it works...it displays for me this output:
{"id":"2","subject":"ss","location":null,"description":null,"starttime":"2014-05-26 01:00:00","endtime":"2014-05-26 02:00:00"}

So as you can you see here, the problem is in the two lines:

var id=data1.id;
document.write(id);